# How can I efficiently extract the first element of a futures::Stream in a blocking manner?

Tags: stream, rust

I've got the following method:

```
pub fn load_names(&self, req: &super::MagicQueryType) -> ::grpcio::Result<::grpcio::ClientSStreamReceiver<String>> {
```

My goal is to get the very first element of [`grpcio::ClientSStreamReceiver`](https://docs.rs/grpcio/0.4.4/grpcio/struct.ClientSStreamReceiver.html); I don't care about the other names:

```
let name: String = load_names(query)?.wait().nth(0)?;
```

It seems inefficient to call `wait()` before `nth(0)` as I believe `wait()` blocks the stream until it receives all the elements.

How can I write a more efficient solution (i.e., `nth(0).wait()`) without triggering build errors? Rust's build errors for `futures::stream::Stream` look extremely confusing to me.

The [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) doesn't support `grpcio = "0.4.4"` so I cannot provide a link.

Comment: Just because the Playground doesn't have a crate doesn't mean that you shouldn't provide a MCVE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To extract the first element of a `futures::Stream` in a blocking manner, you should convert the `Stream` to an iterator by calling [`executor::block_on_stream`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.4/futures/executor/fn.block_on_stream.html) and then call [`Iterator::next`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.next).

```
use futures::{executor, stream, Stream}; // 0.3.4
use std::iter;

fn example() -> impl Stream<Item = i32> {
    stream::iter(iter::repeat(42))
}

fn main() {
    let v = executor::block_on_stream(example()).next();
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

If you are using Tokio, you can convert the `Stream` into a `Future` with [`StreamExt::into_future`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.4/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.into_future) and annotate a function with [`#[tokio::main]`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.16/tokio/attr.main.html):

```
use futures::{stream, Stream, StreamExt}; // 0.3.4
use std::iter;
use tokio; // 0.2.13

fn example() -> impl Stream<Item = i32> {
    stream::iter(iter::repeat(42))
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn just_one() -> Option<i32> {
    let (i, _stream) = example().into_future().await;
    i
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", just_one());
}
```

See also:

- [How do I synchronously return a value calculated in an asynchronous Future in stable Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52521201/155423)
- [How to select between a future and stream in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42928432/155423)