# How do I convert a Stream into a Future?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, stream, future

I have an asynchronous [`Stream`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html) and I'd like to get the first value out of it. How can I do so?

```rust
use futures::Stream; // 0.3.5

async fn example<T>(s: impl Stream<Item = T>) -> Option<T> {
    todo!("What goes here?")
}
```

Comment: Note that this question is because I had an answer for another post that was poorly titled and edited, and ultimately the answer was irrelevant. Rather than just delete it, I'm making it into a self-answered question.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`StreamExt::next`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.next):

```rust
use futures::{Stream, StreamExt}; // 0.3.5

async fn example<T>(mut s: impl Stream<Item = T> + Unpin) -> Option<T> {
    s.next().await
}
```

You can use [`StreamExt::into_future`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.into_future):

```rust
use futures::{FutureExt, Stream, StreamExt}; // 0.3.5

async fn example<T>(s: impl Stream<Item = T> + Unpin) -> Option<T> {
    s.into_future().map(|(v, _)| v).await
}
```

In rare cases, you may want to use [`future::poll_fn`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/future/fn.poll_fn.html) to have complete control:

```rust
use futures::{future, task::Poll, Stream, StreamExt}; // 0.3.5

async fn example<T>(mut s: impl Stream<Item = T> + Unpin) -> Option<T> {
    future::poll_fn(|ctx| {
        // Could use methods like `Poll::map` or
        // the `?` operator instead of a `match`.
        match s.poll_next_unpin(ctx) {
            Poll::Ready(v) => {
                // Do any special logic here
                Poll::Ready(v)
            }
            Poll::Pending => Poll::Pending,
        }
    })
    .await
}
```

See also:

- [How to convert a Future into a Stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59982803/155423)

### More broadly

If you wanted to act upon all the values in the stream, producing a single value, you can use [`StreamExt::fold`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.fold):

```rust
use futures::{Stream, StreamExt}; // 0.3.5

async fn example(s: impl Stream + Unpin) -> usize {
    s.fold(0, |st, _| async move { st + 1 }).await
}
```

If you wanted to act upon all the values in the stream without producing a value, you can use [`StreamExt::for_each`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.for_each):

```
use futures::{Stream, StreamExt}; // 0.3.5

async fn example<I: std::fmt::Debug>(s: impl Stream<Item = I> + Unpin) {
    s.for_each(|i| async {
        dbg!(i);
    })
    .await;
}
```

See also:

- [How to select between a future and stream in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42928432/155423)

### `Unpin`

These example all require that the incoming `Stream` implement `Unpin`. You could also pin the stream yourself via [`Box::pin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.pin) or the [`pin_mut!`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/macro.pin_mut.html) macro.

See also:

- [What are the use cases of the newly proposed Pin type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49913846/155423)